# Visual Studio Installer не скачивает установочные файлы еще на стадии подготовки (VS2022)

Tags: visual-studio

Впервые столкнулся с проблемой во время попытки установки VS2022 Community, скачивая инсталлер с официального сайта по этой ссылке [VS2022 Community](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/ru/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=Community&channel=Release&version=VS2022&source=VSLandingPage&passive=false&cid=2030)

Не скачивает установочные файлы  все по 0%. Пробовал другие версии и 2019 скачать - не выходит, та же проблема...
[image: Сначала так..]

Потом, после ожидания примерно с 15 минут, появляется окно с ошибкой
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите разобраться с этой проблемой! На данный момент у меня стоит VS2019, сейчас же вообще никакую не могу поставить. У всех так же?

Благодарю!

Comment: vpn bro :) мне помог только vpn

Comment: Использовал расширения для Chrome: Browsec и ZenMate. По новой скачивал - не помогло. Поделитесь, пожалуйста, какой vpn использовали?

Comment: Санкции работают?

Comment: @PetruhaSkilluha вам нужен vpn не на трафик из браузера, а на трафик пк. Я устанавливал себе QT через Proton первый попавшийся в гугле на запрос - vpn for pc

Comment: @CrazyElf насчет студии не знаю, обновления от ms для 2022 вроде проходят. Устанавливал с нуля vs 2015, требовался vpn(скачка образа(или архива не помню) была с сайта) . Так же для qt - установщик с сайта скачивается, но далее сам не дает добро на установку, решилось все vpn'om.

Comment: Могу посоветовать Planet vpn, в протон не зайти(, нашёл вот такую альтернативу (тоже без трафика)

Answer (score 5):

tomato-magnet-regulato, вы были правы, помог десктопный впн ProtonVPN, правда не мог найти поначалу сервер (Быстрый запуск не помог), но нашел Нидерланды-47, и все стало скачиваться и устанавливаться.
Спасибо, Вам, большое!

Comment: пожалуйста подскажите как вы воспользовались ProtonVPN, его заблокировали в России, у меня впн скачался, но войти в учетку не получилось, после этого я скачал другой впн, чтобы зайти в Protonvpn, зашел, но к серверам подключиться всё равно не получается, буду благодарен, если поможете

Comment: @Nigawai скачал с официального сайта, зарегистрировав аккаунт по этой ссылке https://account.protonvpn.com/signup?plan=free&billing=1&minimumCycle=1&currency=EUR&language=ru
Потом методом проверки каждого из серверов, подключаясь к нему в ручную, выбирая самые незагруженные сервера, т.к. "Быстрое подключение" не дало результатов. Я, например на данный момент могу подключиться к серверу Нидерланды->NL-FREE#47.