# Проблема с установкой Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

Устанавливается ~ 2гб из 6, после чего установка зависает и заново начинает скачивать с 1.8гб, пока не доходит до 2гб. И так по кругу

Comment: Пробовал сбрасывать установку и начинать заново, не помогло. Пробовал "установка при скачивании" и "установка после скачивания"

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1453995/visual-studio-installer-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d1%87%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d1%8b-%d0%b5%d1%89%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b8?noredirect=1#comment2597825_1453995

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Visual Studio Installer не скачивает установочные файлы еще на стадии подготовки (VS2022)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1453995/visual-studio-installer-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d1%87%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d1%8b-%d0%b5%d1%89%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b8)

Comment: Попробуйте советы по ссылкам. Если `VPN` поможет, напишите, закрою вопрос как дубликат тогда.

Comment: я переустановил installer, попробовал изменить файл hosts (помогло при установке инсталлера), но теперь я получаю ошибку манифест установщика не прошел проверку подписи. В hosts добавил 93.184.215.201 download.visualstudio.microsoft.com

Comment: протон впн не может подключиться к серверу, пробовал warp, при его запуске у меня вообще исчезает подключение к интернету, openVPN GUI не помог

Comment: ВПН помог, но установка заняла около 10 часов