# Всем привет. Не устанавливается Visual Studio 2019-2022

Tags: visual-studio

Скачал установочник VS community 2019-2022, пытаюсь установить ничего не происходит [image: Установка VS], облазил кучу сайтов все перепробовал ничего не помогает, после завершения пишет что плохое интернет соединение установка прервана.
[image: После завершения программы спустя минут 20]
Операционная система win10, уже сбросил до заводского состояния систему и все равно такая ситуация, брандмауэр отключал, NOD32 отключал ничего не помогает.
на зарубежных сайтах пишут чтоб в файле hosts прописал IP-адрес какой то, ничего не помогает.

Comment: дубликаты: [1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1457117/178576), [2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1454769/178576)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Visual Studio Installer не скачивает установочные файлы еще на стадии подготовки (VS2022)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1453995/visual-studio-installer-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d1%87%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d1%8b-%d0%b5%d1%89%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b8)