# Проблема с установкой Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio

Не могу установить `Visual Studio` на ПК, весь инет перерыл. Проблема в том, что на этапе запуска установщика `VS installer` он отказывается подключатся к интернету и говорит, что невозможно подключится к интернету, хотя интернет у меня есть и с системой всё хорошо.

[image: Ошибка подключения]

Comment: А для чего вам vs 2019?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1453995/visual-studio-installer-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d1%87%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d1%8b-%d0%b5%d1%89%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b8

Comment: программировать

Comment: @Axiles ещё раз, для чего вам  vs **2019**

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Visual Studio Installer не скачивает установочные файлы еще на стадии подготовки (VS2022)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1453995/visual-studio-installer-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d1%87%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d1%8b-%d0%b5%d1%89%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b8)

Comment: еще раз отвечаю - программировать (С++)

Comment: @Axiles Известно ли вам о наличии vs 2022?

Comment: разумеется, но мне 19 нужна, на моем железе это самый оптимальный вариант

Answer (score 0):

Подмените свой IP. Я например использовал "ProxySwitcherStandard". Без танцев с бубном.