# Ошибка при скачивании Visual Studio Community 2022

Tags: visual-studio-2022

Прилетело обновление VS, начал обновлять, инсталлер не смог скачать некоторые файлы. Решил переустановить, теперь выдаёт такое:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Visual Studio Installer не скачивает установочные файлы еще на стадии подготовки (VS2022)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1453995/visual-studio-installer-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d1%87%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d1%8b-%d0%b5%d1%89%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b8)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуй через VPN установку начать. Мне только так помогло.